# Magento 2 How to create table setting with image upload in admin system configuration?

Tags: magento2, configuration, image

I did it:

[image]

**system.xml**

```
<field id="active" translate="label" sortOrder="220" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>active buy</label>
    <frontend_model>[Vendor]\[Ext]\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Active</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
</field>
```

**active.php**

```
....

protected function _prepareToRender() {
    $this->addColumn('col_1', ['label' => __('Column 1'),  'renderer' => false]);
    $this->addColumn('col_2', ['label' => __('Column 2'),  'renderer' => false]);

    $this->_addAfter = false;
    $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
}

...
```

**Standart field upload image.**
[image]

As instead of "Column 2" to put the "Standart field upload image"?
Need that all worked successfully when you click the add button.

Answer (score 0):

For customizing of single column rendering, you need to add renderer in column configuration.

```
$fileInputRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(MyFileRenderer::class);
$this->addColumn(
    'col_2',
    [
        'label' => __('Column 2'),
        'renderer' => $fileInputRenderer
    ]
);
```

Custom renderer must extend from `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock` and must renderer template for column cell.

*Example:*

```
class MyFileRenderer extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $column = $this->getColumn();

        return '<input type="file" />';
    }
}
```

Note, that html rendering in PHP class is not good idea, you can use `*.phtml` template file for this.

Comment: Thanks. It good worked. But how upload image in media magento?

Comment: This is just another question. I think, that you need to use Ajax file uploading with js components for fill configuration values. Alternatively you can add custom plugin or observer for saving of requested images.

Comment: @Max col_2 values are not save in database also.
Please check this